# How to override List.Add method?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, overriding

Currently I have a error logging class like so:

```
public class Log
{
    public enum LogTypes
    {
        Info = 1,
        Error = 2,
        Warning = 3
    }


    public string Message { get; set; }
    public LogTypes LogType { get; set; }


    public Log(string Message, LogTypes LogType)
    {
        this.Message = Message;
        this.LogType = LogType;
    }
```

I have this initialiser for a new list:

```
List<Log> LogList = new List<Log>();
```

How can I use `LogList.Add(Message, LogType)` instead of `LogList.Add(new Log(Message, LogType));`?

I know it is a minor change but I am still learning C# and am curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, I wouldn't do this. It's not what anyone using a `List<Log>` would expect. Rather than exposing a plain `List<Log>`, consider creating a `Logger` class or something similar which *contains* a `List<Log>` and exposes a `Log(string message, LogType type)` method, but doesn't actually expose the `List<Log>`.

If you *really* want to be able to call `Add(message, type)` directly on the list, there are two options:

- Create a new class derived from `List<Log>`:

  ```
  public LogList : List<Log>
  {
      public void Add(string message, LogType type)
      {
          Add(new Log(message, type));
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that this is *overloading* (adding a new method signature but with the same name, `Add`), not *overriding* (providing new behaviour for an existing signature method for a `virtual` method) - and you'll need to create an instance of `LogList` rather than `List<Log>`:

  ```
  LogList list = new LogList();
  list.Add(message, type);
  ```
- Add an extension method to `List<Log>`, which will effectively add that method to *all* `List<Log>` instances.

  ```
  public static LogListExtensions
  {
      public static void Add(this Log<List> list, string message, LogType type)
      {
          list.Add(new Log(message, type));
      }
  }
  ```

As an aside, I'd probably also remove the setters from your `Log` type - why would you need to be able to change the message or type after construction?

Comment: I went with the Logger class. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class derived from `List` and define new `Add` method for your needs, e.g.:

```
public class MyListClass : List<Log>
{
    public void Add(string message, Log.LogTypes logType)
    {
        this.Add(new Log(message, logType));
    }
}
```

Comment: but that's not overriding :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Well overriding with the given method is impossible, given that it's not part of the existing class. The OP has just confused overloading and overriding, which is a fairly common mistake.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh.. I overlooked just because of override keyword :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not going make any difference apart from saving a second or two of typing. Having said that you can always implement your own list class and use that. Or you could make use of extension methods.